# Jquery this.find is not a function

Tags: jquery

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here?  I'm trying to iterate through table rows and then get the .user-cell text for each row with a checked checkbox.

```
$('table tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function () {
  var user = $(this).find('.user-cell').text();
})
```

Comment: It would be HUGELY useful to see the HTML. Please click edit, then `[<>]` snippet editor and provide a [mcve]

Comment: remember that this refers to the checked checkbox, not the tr. so maybe consider adding `.closest("tr")` before your find, but as @mplungjan says, without your html we cant tell you 100% what the problem is.

Comment: Try `const texts = $(':checkbox:checked').map(function () {
  return $(this).closest("tr").find('.user-cell').text();
}).get().join(",")`